# Why is my string comparison in Bash always evaluated as true?

Tags: string, bash

I have a script checking if a file is up-to-minute.

```
updatedate=`ls -l file | sed -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -d' ' -f7` #cut the modification time
nowdate=`date +"%H:%M"`
echo "$updatedate $nowdate"
if [ "$updatedate"="$nowdate" ]
then
  echo 'OK'
else
  echo 'NOT OK'
fi
```

But when I run it, the comparison is always true:

```
$ ./checkfile
10:04 10:07
OK

$ ./checkfile
10:07 10:07
OK
```

Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a space on each side of the equals sign.

```
if [ "$updatedate" = "$nowdate" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate all the arguments to `test` with whitespace. As it stands you have `=` right up against its two operands so `test` sees one argument, not the three that you intend.

Comment: [ is a shorthand for test, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html (that comment is for the OP) ;)